# “Inconsistent stackmap frames” exception when trying to create a new object

Tags: maven, unit-testing, java-7, powermockito, verifyerror

I'm having trouble to write a Unit Test because I'm getting this exception when trying to create a new object of EquifaxDLPingRequest class. I've simplified the code just to show the problem:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({EquifaxDLPingRequest.class})
public class SimpleTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    EquifaxDLPingRequest equifaxDLPingRequest = new EquifaxDLPingRequest("");
  }

}
```

When the **equifaxDLPingRequest** is created I'm having this exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 46
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/dealflo/vhub/maintenance/passwordchanger/AbstractMaintenanceRequest.<init>(Lorg/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass;)V @46: aload_2
  Reason:
    Type uninitializedThis (current frame, locals[2]) is not assignable to 'com/dealflo/vhub/maintenance/passwordchanger/AbstractMaintenanceRequest' (stack map, locals[2])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @32
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'org/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass', uninitializedThis, 'org/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass', top, 'java/lang/Object' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/Object', 'java/lang/Object' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @46
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'org/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass', 'com/dealflo/vhub/maintenance/passwordchanger/AbstractMaintenanceRequest', 'org/powermock/core/IndicateReloadClass' }
    stack: { }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b 4e4d 12d7 b800 6a04 bd00 1b59 032d
    0000010: 5312 d8b8 00ce b800 da3a 0519 05b2 002b
    0000020: a500 0e2a 01c0 002d b700 dca7 000a 2c2d
    0000030: b700 dc01 57b1                         
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@46,Object[#16],Object[#45])
    chop_frame(@53,2)

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassObject(Desc.java:44)
    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getClassType(Desc.java:153)
    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:123)
    at javassist.runtime.Desc.getType(Desc.java:79)
    at com.dealflo.vhub.maintenance.passwordchanger.SimpleTest.test(SimpleTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The exception is thown only when I add @PrepareForTest({EquifaxDLPingRequest.class}) but I have to use PowerMockito and @PrepareForTest({EquifaxDLPingRequest.class}) because later I have to mock a local variable.
I know about the *-XX:-UseSplitVerifier* and *-noverify* jvm options but I can't use them in my project.
Can anyone explain why this is happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Perhaps, you’re using a version of powermockito that is out of date. Generally, this kind of exception indicates that either, the compiler has bugs or there’s a bytecode transformation tool not doing its job right. When you say, it happens when you add an annotation that will trigger Instrumentation, it is obvious who’s to blame.

Comment: It could be an issue with Javassist. Try to use latest version of Javassist.

Comment: I've set javassist 3.18.2-GA it the exception gone. Thanks a lot!